# Contours counting and labeling

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to develop a program that counts the number of `contourAreas` as function of size and display it to the user.

I was able to create `drawContours` to all the areas but I would like to add a text label under each `contouArea` and display there respective size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started. To go through all the contours you have to use the for loop with h_next below. If you want to find out more I really recommend Gary Bradski's book Learning OpenCv. THere are some great examples on contour finding in the book.

```
CvMemStorage* contour_storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvSeq* contours;
CvFont font;
cvInitFont(&font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6f, 0.6f, 0, 2);
cvFindContours(sourceImage, contour_storage, &contours, sizeof (CvContour), CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

for (CvSeq* d = contours; d != NULL; d = d->h_next) {
 CvRect iconBox = cvBoundingRect(d, 0);
 CvPoint center = cvPoint(iconBox.x + (iconBox.width / 2), iconBox.y + (iconBox.height / 2));
 int area = abs(cvContourArea(d, CV_WHOLE_SEQ));
 cvPutText(sourceImage,"area", center, &font, CV_RGB(255, 255, 255));
}
```

Comment: Hi diip_thomas,

Thank you very much for your reply and advice. I tried you bite of code and it works. :)

I'll buy the book as I really need to learn this library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the open cv function [putText](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#puttext)

I guess that you know how to retrieve the position of your contour center, isn' it ?

Comment: Hi abarral,
Thank you for replying.Unfortunately English isn't my first language and I think my question isn't well formulated. Sorry.
What I'm trying to achieve is to measure each contourArea and display with a surrounding circle there respective location and under each circle there respective area and a text label.
My questions are the following:
How I can display individually a contourArea (countours[0][1]???) and there respective circle using (drawContour)?
How I can add a text label under each circle?
I had e a view in Opencv Help for puText but I'm not sure how to implement?